# How to query one field then order by another one in Firebase cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling to make a (not so) complex query in firebase cloud firestore.

I simply need to get all docs `where` the `id` field  `==` a given id.

Then order the results by their `date` and limit to 10 results.

So this is my current situation

```js
db.firestore().collection('comments')
        .where("postId",'==',idOfThePost)
        .orderBy('date','asc').limit(10).get().then( snapshot => {
           //Nothing happens and the request wasn't even been executed
         })
```

I can get the result only if i don't use the `orderBy` query but i have to  process this sorting for the needs of my application.

Someone has an idea to help me to fix this ?

thanks

Comment: are this `idOfThePost` unique id's?

Comment: Actually it's a unique id for each post but each comment of the related post have a field named postId to identify the post it belongs to. so many comments are sharing the same `postId` value.

Comment: how you saving you r date?

Comment: `date` is a basic field in a `num` format `Date.now()`. there is a date field in each doc `postId` and `comment`

Comment: try to send a server timestamp form sdk and check `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Comment: @Hareesh I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, i've just tried this and nothing new.

Comment: Have the same issue with their Android SDK, as soon as orderBy is introduced, no result is returned. Suspect the SDK is broken for now.

Comment: Just pointing out that your "postId" is surrounded by double quotes, whereas 'date' is surrounded by single quotes.  Change "postId" to 'postId'.  Also, make sure the field in your doc is "date" and not "Date" or "DATE"... Then, try taking out 'asc' for ascending.  It should automatically sort in ascending order, I believe.  Let me know if any of that helps.

Answer (score 14):

**You can do this by creating an Index in the firestore.**

The first field of the index should be the equality field and the second field of the index should be the order by field.

Given your problem, you would need the following index:

```
first field: postId, 'asc'
second field: date, 'asc'
```

Comment: First, thanks you, your answer is the ONE ! If it is the first time someone use index, be careful to use the same ordering in your code. For exampe : postId is "==" condition so you don't have tu use an ordering, but with orderBy("data", "asc"), you have to let "asc" ordering. If you want a "desc" ordering, you have to create the index for "desc".

Answer (score 5):

Please check the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data). It says

> However, if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field

you can try this code

```
db.firestore().collection('comments')
    .where("postId",'==',idOfThePost)
    .orderBy('postId')
    .orderBy('date','asc').limit(10).get().then( snapshot => {
       .....
     })
```

Comment: I do read the docs and i've tried this but without success. And the docs says `range comparison` However `==` isn't a range comparison operator therefore this part of the doc does not apply to `==` . Am I right ?

Comment: `==` is **not** a range comparison.

Answer (score 3):

## My Workaround

If you're googling this you've probably realized it can't be done traditionally. Depending on your problem though there may be some viable workarounds, I just finished creating this one.

## Scenario

We have an app that has posts that appear in a feed (kind of like Reddit), each post has an algorithmic score 'score' and we needed a way to get the 'top posts' from 12-24 hours ago. Trying to query sorted by 'score' where timestamp uses > and < to build the 12-24 hour ago range fails since Firebase doesn't allow multiple conditional querying or single conditional querying with an descending sort on another field.

## Solution

What we ended up doing is using a second field that was an array since you can compound queries for array-contains and descending. At the time a post was made we knew the current hour, suppose it was hour 10000 since the server epoch (i.e. `floor(serverTime/60.0/60.0)`). We would create an array called `arrayOfHoursWhenPostIsTwelveToTwentyFourHoursOld` and in that array we would populate the following values:

```
int hourOffset = 12;
while (hourOffset <= 24) {
    [arrayOfHoursWhenPostIsTwelveToTwentyFourHoursOld addObject:@(currentHour+hourOffset)];
    hourOffset++;
}
```

Then, when making the post we would store that array under the field `hoursWhenPostIsTwelveToTwentyFourHoursOld`

THEN, if it had been, say, 13 hours since the post was made (the post was made at hour 10000) then the current hour would be 10013, so we could use the array-contains query to see if our array contained the value `10013` while also sorting by algorithm score at the same time

Like so:

```
FIRFirestore *firestore = [Server sharedFirestore];
FIRCollectionReference *collection = [firestore collectionWithPath:@"Posts"];
FIRQuery *query = [collection queryOrderedByField:@"postsAlgorithmScore" descending:YES];
query = [query queryWhereField:@"hoursWhenPostIsTwelveToTwentyFourHoursOld" arrayContains:@(currentHour)];
query = [query queryLimitedTo:numberToLoad];
```

## Almost Done

The above code will not run properly at first since it is using a compound index query, so we had to create a compound index query in firebase, the easiest way to do this is just run the query then look at the error in the logs and firebase SDK will generate a link for you that you can navigate to and it will auto-generate the compound index for your database for you, otherwise you can navigate to firebase>database>index>compound>new and build it yourself using `hoursWhenTwelveToTwentyFourHoursOld: Arrays, score: Descending`

## Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

same here, it is weird why can't. below is another sample. can't get the result. Hoping firebase can reply about this and update the document.

```
dbFireStore.collection('room').where('user_id.'+global.obj_user.user_id,'==',true).orderBy('last_update').get().then((qs)=>{
  console.log(qs);
});
```

using other work-around solution is javascript [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) and [array.sort()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue yesterday on Android. The Callback was just not called. Today I suddenly got an error message. `FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index.` It even contains a URL in the error message to generate that index with one click.

It seems that if you want to use `orderBy` on your data, you need to create an index for that field. The index also needs to be in the correct order (DESC, ASC).

Comment: Are not simple indexes created automatically? How to create index on only one field? Or is it where  condition FIELD + Orderby FIELD as index?

Comment: @Pavan As far as I've noticed, as soon as an `orderBy` is introduced it needs an index. For a `where` I'm fairly certain that an index is not needed.

Comment: @GillesBraun Correct. From the docs: `Cloud Firestore requires an index for every query, to ensure the best performance. All document fields are automatically indexed, so queries that only use equality clauses don't need additional indexes. `

Answer (score 1):

As per [firestore document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message),

**If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.**

So just click that link you get in Logcat, it will be redirected to create index page, just create index. It will take some time. after enabling composite index, you will get the result as your requested query.

Comment: This solves the problem of the original question. But in those cases where you are querying on a field that changes such as `userId.<an_actual_id_that_is_different_for_every_user>` you would need a compound index per user, which is not scalable as at the moment Firestore only allows a few hundreds of these compound indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this looking for help when i found that using the orderBy function didnt work and the documentation still says it does not support it. A bit weird and unclear to be honest, because it does support it so long as you index your Firestore database. For example, this query now works fine for me having set up indexing:

```
const q = query(docRef, where("category", "==", 'Main'), orderBy('title', 'asc')
```

[Indexing in Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acltZ.png)

[Console Log that even gives you the url to automatically create the index if you try and run with the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ5Zz.jpg).

Maybe I am missing something, or a later version of Firebase (I am using v9) simply does support it.