# Angular Firestore Collection Query & Order By

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am performign a simple query and then want to order by date.

This works perfectly fine:

```
this.afs.collection('orders', ref=> ref.where('orderStatus', '<', 7));
```

This throws an error when I want to filter orderStaus < 7 and then order it by date.

```
this.afs.collection('orders', ref=> ref.where('orderStatus', '<', 7).orderBy('date', 'desc'));
```

Here is my error:

```
You have a where filter with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) on field 'orderStatus' and so you must also use 'orderStatus' as your first Query.orderBy(), but your first Query.orderBy() is on field 'date' instead.
```

How can I achieve getting all ordersStatus < 7 AND then sort the orders by date?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1046#issuecomment-427148764

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47079683/6294072

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore requires you to first order by the field on which you are applying the range filter on and then order by any other field of your choice.

**Reference**: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

You can achieve this by creating a compound index of range filter field and the field you want to order next for the collection you are querying.

So in your case you need to create a compound index for the `orders` collection with `orderStatus DESC` and `date DESC`.

**Reference**: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Hope this is useful.