# I can't order my firestore data by multiple fields. React

Tags: reactjs, database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called `list` which I'm trying to order by 3 different fields: `important`, `unimportant` and `date`, so the `unimportant` come first (they'll be at the bottom of the list, `important` the last, and all that sorted by timestamp.

If i query to order my docs by any of the above on its own, then it works, trouble starts when I try to put them together as per firestore documentation. So I have the following code:

```
const q = query(listRef, orderBy("important", "desc"), orderBy("unimportant"), orderBy("date"));
```

Which gets me Uncaught Error in snapshot listener. This is how i get my data from firestore:

```
const getData = () => {                                       // get data from firestore to app

onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  firestoreList = [];
  firestoreIds = [];
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    firestoreList.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
    !firestoreIds.includes(doc.id) && firestoreIds.push(doc.id);
  });
  if (firestoreList.length === 0) {
    setItems(items.concat(newItem));
  } else {
    setItemIds(firestoreIds);
    setItems(firestoreList);
  }
});

}

useEffect(() => {
getData();

}, []);
```

I'm using `onSnapshot`, because i need the user to be able to add, remove and do other stuff with data and see the outcome reflected immediately for them and for other users who'll be using the app simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering/filtering on multiple fields requires that your database contains a so-called composite index on those fields. And unlike single-field indexes, which are created automatically, composite indexes are only created when you explicitly tell the database to do so.

If you log the warning/error message you get, it contains a long direct link  to the Firestore console to create the exact index the query needs. The link has all details already filled in, so all you have to do is click the link and then click the button to start creating the index.

Also see:

- [Firestore order by two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381713/firestore-order-by-two-fields)
- [How to query one field then order by another one in Firebase cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065982/how-to-query-one-field-then-order-by-another-one-in-firebase-cloud-firestore)
- the Firestore documentation on [ordering a Firestore query on multiple fields](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-query-order-multi).

Comment: thanks for that, i was trying to log error message with trycatch block, but that didn't log anything, whatever i did i would just get Uncaught error in snapshot listnerer, so i cooked up a work around solution, I've created another parameter that would be just a timestamp if item was a regular item, then it would substract an amount from timestamp if item was important or added an amount if item was unimportant and then sorted my collection by that new parameter. But it's good to know that there is a solution, next time I'll try to look into it more deeply.